# What happened at Fatima on 13 October 1917?

Tags: catholic-church, miracle

It is widely claimed (mostly by religious people) that there was a miracle in [Fátima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1tima,_Portugal) where the sun "danced". It is known as the [miracle of the sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_Sun).

Is there any scientific consensus that anything scientifically relevant happened, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Hello @João, welcome to our site! I've slightly changed the tone of your question so it is neutral as to the veracity of the miracle.

Comment: [Plenty of explanations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_Sun#Critical_evaluation_of_the_event) here. Nothing was measured by scientific stations (according to the Church) so, basically, scientifically all that happened was in the minds of the witnesses. Of course, that's also why the Church calls it a "miracle"...

Comment: Thanks. In hindsight the question really was poorly phrased.

Comment: I dare you to stare for a prolonged time directly into the sun and not starting to see it dance... Or, wait, no, on the other hand, I strongly recommend you don't stare into the sun for a prolonged amount of time.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to bring facts to bear on this so I don't think it makes a good question.

Comment: @matt_black can you expand on that?